# Class CoreCDP is implemented in both fram

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I got a crash on my Xcode with the following message, while I'm trying to run some UITests !

[image]

I tried multiple solutions :
1- I've added this piece of code to my podfile, that someone had suggested it on another question or article on the Internet

```
def remove_duplicated_frameworks(app_pod_name, installer)
    test_targets = get_test_targets(app_pod_name, installer)
    puts "Detected test targets: #{test_targets}"

    puts "Removing duplicated frameworks from OTHER_LDFLAGS"
    targets = installer.aggregate_targets.select { |x| !test_targets.include?(x.name) }

    # Checks each pair of targets if they have common pods. Duplicates are removed from the first one's xcconfig.
    for i in 0..targets.size-1 do
        target = targets[i]
        remainingAppPodTargets = targets[i+1..targets.size-1].flat_map(&:pod_targets)

        target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
            # Removes all frameworks which exist in other pods
            remainingAppPodTargets
                .flat_map { |pod_target| get_framework_names(pod_target) }
                .each { |framework| config_file.frameworks.delete(framework) }

            # Saves updated xcconfig
            xcconfig_path = target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
            config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
        end
    end
end

def get_test_targets(app_pod_name, installer)
    main_target_name = app_pod_name.gsub("Pods-", "")

    installer.aggregate_targets
        .find { |x| x.name == app_pod_name }
        .user_project
        .targets
        .select { |x| x.test_target_type? }
        .flat_map { |x| ["Pods-#{x}", "Pods-#{main_target_name}-#{x}"] }
        .select { |x| installer.aggregate_targets.map(&:name).include?(x) }
        .uniq
end

def get_framework_names(pod_target)
    frameworkNames = pod_target.specs.flat_map do |spec|
        # We should take framework names from 'vendored_frameworks'.
        # If it's not defined, we use 'spec.name' instead.
        #
        # spec.name can be defined like Framework/Something - we take the first part
        # because that's what appears in OTHER_LDFLAGS.
        frameworkPaths = unless spec.attributes_hash['ios'].nil?
            then spec.attributes_hash['ios']['vendored_frameworks']
            else spec.attributes_hash['vendored_frameworks']
            end || [spec.name.split(/\//, 2).first]

        map_paths_to_filenames(frameworkPaths)
    end

    frameworkNames.uniq
end

def map_paths_to_filenames(paths)
    Array(paths).map(&:to_s).map do |filename|
        extension = File.extname filename
        File.basename filename, extension
    end
end
```

2- The first solution didn't work so I tried to replace it with this piece of code, and run "pod install" and nothing happens too

```
sharedLibrary = installer.aggregate_targets.find { |aggregate_target| aggregate_target.name == 'Pods-[MY_FRAMEWORK_TARGET]' }
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
        if aggregate_target.name == 'Pods-[MY_APP_TARGET]'
            aggregate_target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
                sharedLibraryPodTargets = sharedLibrary.pod_targets
                aggregate_target.pod_targets.select { |pod_target| sharedLibraryPodTargets.include?(pod_target) }.each do |pod_target|
                    pod_target.specs.each do |spec|
                        frameworkPaths = unless spec.attributes_hash['ios'].nil? then spec.attributes_hash['ios']['vendored_frameworks'] else spec.attributes_hash['vendored_frameworks'] end || Set.new
                        frameworkNames = Array(frameworkPaths).map(&:to_s).map do |filename|
                            extension = File.extname filename
                            File.basename filename, extension
                        end
                    end
                    frameworkNames.each do |name|
                        if name != '[DUPLICATED_FRAMEWORK_1]' && name != '[DUPLICATED_FRAMEWORK_2]'
                            raise("Script is trying to remove unwanted flags: #{name}. Check it out!")
                        end
                        puts "Removing #{name} from OTHER_LDFLAGS"
                        config_file.frameworks.delete(name)
                    end
                end
            end
            xcconfig_path = aggregate_target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
            config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
        end
    end
```

3- For this solution I tried to make `use_frameworks!` a globale in my podfile, but didn't work either !
I still have the same crash and my UITests don't work !

Any help please ?